# Program to track file / directory changes in Linux

Tags: files, security, sandbox

I am currently trying to make a sandbox environment that enables me to open potential Phishing e-mails in a safe environment. There are other articles on this in the security stack exchange (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32928/how-do-i-safely-inspect-a-suspicious-email-attachment) that use a Windows 7 build in order to do this and use a program called 'what changed' in order to automatically track any alterations.

Is there a Linux equivalent to this? I've created a Ubuntu VM in virtual box and was hoping to use this rather than a Windows 7 build.

Comment: You can check inotify. https://techarena51.com/blog/inotify-tools-example/